# Extractall for the dates ending with 'st','nd', 'rd','th' while swapping days with months using RegEx

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, date, regex-group

I have got these dates within text in a pandas dataframe column.

```
import pandas as pd
sr = pd.Series(['text Mar 20, 2009 text', 'text March 20, 2009 text', 'text 20 Mar. 2009 text', 'text Sep 2010 text','text Mar 20th, 2009 text ','text Mar 21st, 2009 text'])
```

when I use regex, I get this.

```
a=sr.str.extractall(r'((?P<day>(?:\d{2} )?(?P<month>(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z,.]*)) (?:\d{2}[-/th|st|nd|rd\s]*[,.]* )?(?P<year>\d{4}))')


       all              day     month  year
match               
0   0   Mar 20, 2009    Mar      Mar    2009
1   0   March 20, 2009  March    March  2009
2   0   20 Mar. 2009    20 Mar.  Mar.   2009
3   0   Sep 2010        Sep      Sep    2010
4   0   Mar 20th, 2009  Mar      Mar    2009
5   0   Mar 21st, 2009  Mar      Mar    2009
```

How can I get the dates (20,20th,21st...) into the day column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution with pandas (why reinvent the wheel?):

```py
    import pandas as pd
    df = sr.to_frame(name='all')
    df['all'] = pd.to_datetime(df['all'])
    df['day'] = df['all'].dt.day
    df['month'] = df['all'].dt.strftime('%b')
    df['year'] = df['all'].dt.year
```

Output:

```
         all  day month  year
0 2009-03-20   20   Mar  2009
1 2009-03-20   20   Mar  2009
2 2009-03-20   20   Mar  2009
3 2010-09-01    1   Sep  2010
4 2009-03-20   20   Mar  2009
5 2009-03-21   21   Mar  2009
```

Comment: I changed the question.. sorry for any confusion.  one of these strings can be like this ''see above and APS eval of 26 May 1982 Social History Marital Status: Single\n' . anyway, your solution helps, even if its not exactly what I had in mind!

Comment: I was hoping for advice on how to get the same result with regex.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an alternative solution could be making use of the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) with a branch reset group `(?|` to match the day and the month either way around.

The pattern without the named groups:

```
\b((?|(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z,.]*(?: (\d{2}(?:th|st|nd|rd)?)?[,.])?|(\d{2}) (?:(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z,.]*)?) (\d{4}))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c4uplW/1)

```
import pandas as pd
import regex

pattern = r"\b(?P<all>(?|(?P<month>Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z,.]*(?: (?P<day>\d{2}(?:th|st|nd|rd)?)?[,.])?|(?P<day>\d{2}) (?:(?P<month>Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z,.]*)?) (?P<year>\d{4}))"

items = [
    'text Mar 20, 2009 text',
    'text March 20, 2009 text',
    'text 20 Mar. 2009 text',
    'text Sep 2010 text',
    'text Mar 20th, 2009 text ',
    'text Mar 21st, 2009 text'
]
res = map(lambda x: regex.findall(pattern, x)[0], items)
df = pd.DataFrame(res)
df.columns = ['all', 'month', 'day', 'year']
print(df)
```

Output

```
              all month   day  year
0    Mar 20, 2009   Mar    20  2009
1  March 20, 2009   Mar    20  2009
2    20 Mar. 2009   Mar    20  2009
3        Sep 2010   Sep        2010
4  Mar 20th, 2009   Mar  20th  2009
5  Mar 21st, 2009   Mar  21st  2009
```

Comment: glad you're here again, because I have already learned more from you than from a week long coursera's 'applied text mining' course.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with dataframes, but I read some posts and tried a few ways to get the data. Maybe there will be an easier / better answer to get the data, but I think you can use / reuse a part of the pattern to match the dates.

Comment: yeah.. I think I prefer the day column as '20,20,20..21'. without the endings.

Comment: It does not like '?|' in \b(?P<all>(?| , raising an error: unknown extension ?| at position 4. the branch reset you're referring to...I have Python 3.6.5.

Comment: Did you install the regex pypi module?

Comment: @bluetail You can see a test run here https://repl.it/repls/ValidDarkturquoiseCommand If you want the days without the endings, you can match the endings after the group as you can see in the example link.

Comment: so cool! your repl.it.link...  it still does not run with me throwing this error:   ->res = map(lambda x: regex.findall(pattern, x)[0], items), TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator.

Comment: Oeff..I am not sure about that one :-), I Googled a bit, try converting it to a list first `res = list(map(lambda x: regex.findall(pattern, x)[0], items))`